# Import one pod instead of many

Tags: ios, cocoapods

is it possible to import one pod that is equivalent to it's dependencies?

I know I can do it in the Podfile, but what about the actual imports in code?

For example, instead of `import SwiftyJSON` and `import RxSwift`, I'd have only `import AllMyPods`, which is my own pod I created just to aggregate the pods I use.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow, could you give be an example? And what if I'm only using functions?

Comment: I'm sorry too, It's my bad